# Problem while calling jira cloud api from atlassian connect application addon using nodejs

Tags: jira

i am having issues while calling jira cloud api from atlassian connect application using nodejs can someone please help me out with Token verification process i tried using jwt as bearer token but that didn't worked so i tried basic authentication by passing username and password but i don't think that approach is good.

And also jwt will be used for 'addon.checkValidToken()' and 'addon.authenticate()'

Also i tried to find some code snippet on atlassian official documentation but wasn't able to.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried to implement so far

Comment: Are you using any toolkit, like Atlassian Connect for Express for example?

Comment: yes @Ian i am using atlassian connect it suppose to be straight forward.
i even passed in token.. but to no avail ...

Comment: The documentation in https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-connect-express/src/master/ should give you that info. Also, you can create a project template of sorts via `atlas-connect new <project_name>` and you can pattern your code from there.